# ORA-00904: "CITYCODE": invalid identifier in CREATE TABLE

Tags: identifier, ora-00904

So, I'm not very good with sql and am trying to jsut great two tables. one called CITY with PK of Citycode, and Warehouse, which uses Citycode as an FK. And I'm not surprised if even this is wrong.

These are my two CREATE requests:

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
citycode        number(2),
cityname        varchar2(30),
Population      number(7),
Primary Key     (citycode)
);
CREATE TABLE Warehouse
(
whid            number(2),
address         varchar2(30),
capacity        number(7),
capacity_used   number(7),
mgrname         varchar2(30),
mgrgender       varchar2(1),
Primary Key     (whid),
Foreign Key     (citycode) REFERENCES City
);
```

Then when I run these in iSQL I get the error ORA-00904: "CITYCODE": invalid identifier.
All I can find about this error is with SELECT statements.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You do need to create the column that references the other table. Like

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
citycode        number(2),
cityname        varchar2(30),
Population      number(7),
constraint city_pk
                PRIMARY KEY     (citycode)
);

CREATE TABLE Warehouse
(
whid            number(2),
address         varchar2(30),
capacity        number(7),
capacity_used   number(7),
mgrname         varchar2(30),
mgrgender       varchar2(1),
citycode        number(2), <-- note this one
constraint warehouse_pk
                PRIMARY KEY     (whid),
constraint warehouse_fk
                FOREIGN KEY     (citycode)
                REFERENCES City (citycode)
);
```

Comment: Ohh I see now. I am having a bit of trouble grasping constraints but that makes alot of sense now! It's hard when the examples don't match what you are working on. Thank you so much! (I can't vote up the answer because I'm so new, but you deserve it!)